# Nodejs MSSQL how to pool multiple databases simultaneously

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I am building a massive intranet using NodeJS, converting from ASP.Net C#.  I keep running into database errors about cannot use the connection while it is closing or connection must be opened etc.  I am attempting to convert over to connection pooling but am running into issues with it since I am connecting  with (currently) 6 different databases, and being new to Node MSSQL I am kind of at a loss for how to proceed.

Originally I was making a call to "runqueries()" passing in the config data, and from there opening a connection to the desired database.  The connection details were stored in a JSON object in the database.js file.  I am now trying to create the pool in the database.js file and return that as an object to connect.

```
//database.js
const sql = require('mssql');

// const Config = {
//     MCAIntranet: {
//         user: 'username',
//         password: 'password',
//         server: 'mcasql',
//         database: 'MCAIntranet',
//         options: { enableArithAbort: true }
//     },
//     DEV_Intranet: {
//         server: 'mcasql',
//         user: 'username',
//         password: 'password',
//         database: 'DEV_Intranet_Test',
//         options: { enableArithAbort: true }
//     },
//     CMR: {
//         user: 'username',
//         password: 'password',
//         server: 'mcasql',
//         database: 'Corporate_Morning_Reports',
//         options: { enableArithAbort: true }
//     },
//     Lansa: {
//         user: 'username',
//         password: 'password',
//         server: 'mcasql',
//         database: 'LANSA',
//         options: { enableArithAbort: true }
//     },
//     Roles: {
//         user: 'username',
//         password: 'password',
//         server: 'mcasql',
//         database: 'dotNetRolesDB_New',
//         options: { enableArithAbort: true }
//     },
//     PreAuth:{
//         user: 'username',
//         password: 'password',
//         server: 'mcasql',
//         database: 'PreAuth',
//         options: { enableArithAbort: true }
//     }
// }



const CORPIntranet = () => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'dbserver',
        database: 'CORPIntranet',
        options: { enableArithAbort: true }
    })
    .connect().then(pool => pool)
};

const DEV_Intranet = () => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'dbserver',
        database: 'CORPIntranet_Test',
        options: { enableArithAbort: true }
    })
    .connect().then(pool => pool)
};

const CMR = () => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'dbserver',
        database: 'Corporate_Morning_Reports',
        options: { enableArithAbort: true }
    })
    .connect().then(pool => pool)
};

const Lansa = () => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'dbserver',
        database: 'LANSA',
        options: { enableArithAbort: true }
    })
    .connect().then(pool => pool)
};

const Roles = () => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'dbserver',
        database: 'dotNetRolesDB_New',
        options: { enableArithAbort: true }
    })
    .connect().then(pool => pool)
};

const PreAuth = () => {
    new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'dbserver',
        database: 'PreAuth',
        options: { enableArithAbort: true }
    })
    .connect().then(pool => pool)
};

const Config = {
    CORPIntranet: CORPIntranet(),
    DEV_Intranet: DEV_Intranet(),
    CMR: CMR(),
    Lansa: Lansa(),
    Roles: Roles(),
    PreAuth: PreAuth()
}

module.exports = Config;
```

I am calling this using the code `await dataQuery.runQuery(query, config.PreAuth);`

and the runquery() code is

```
//dataQueries.js
let sql = require('mssql');
const runQuery = async (query, database) => {
  try {
      // await sql.connect(database);
      // let request =  new sql.Request();
      let recordset = await database.query(query);
      return recordset;
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
      { error: "dataQueries.js 17" + ex.Message };
      return "False";
    }
    finally{
      sql.close();
    }
 }
```

I know that I don't need the "sql.close()" at the end but I am in the process of conversion.  I am now getting a typeError: database.query is not a function.

If you could point out where my fault lies in this, and better yet link a good tutorial that assumes neophyte status of the reader, that would be excellent.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
In my runQuery() function I changed the code to

```
      let pool=await database();
      let recordset = await pool.query(query);
```

which now allows the query to run.  But is this the correct method and will it prevent errors on multiple database connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in the simplest fashion possible.  I switched from using the mssql module to sequelize.js which gives a level of abstraction from the database access and connectivity, and simplifies access to multiple databases along with database types (MSSQL, Postgres, MongoDB etc)